# Jekyll site running inside docker container but localhost:4000 is not working on host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jekyll, dockerfile

Directory structure:

- docker-compuse.yml
- /faq/.... all the site

In root directory I run `docker-compose up --build` and I get output that site is running:

```
faq-site_1  | Configuration file: /srv/faq/_config.yml
faq-site_1  |             Source: /srv/faq
faq-site_1  |        Destination: /srv/faq/_site
faq-site_1  |  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
faq-site_1  |       Generating... 
faq-site_1  |                     done in 1.37 seconds.
faq-site_1  |  Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/srv/faq'
faq-site_1  | LiveReload address: http://127.0.0.1:35729
faq-site_1  |     Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/faq/
faq-site_1  |   Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

I SSH'ed to the container with `docker exec -it c94ad3af91c9 bash` and executed `curl localhost:4000`. Got expected result of HTML.

I try to run the site on http://127.0.0.1:4000 from the host machine and Chrome fails with "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

I have configured jekyll to run on a subdirectory of `/faq`. Tried accessing

- http://127.0.0.1:4000
- http://127.0.0.1:4000/faq
- http://127.0.0.1:4000/faq/

nothing works. I always get this from chrome:

[image]

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev build-essential
RUN gem install jekyll bundler
RUN gem install jekyll-feed
RUN gem install jekyll-paginate
RUN gem install minima

RUN bundle -v
RUN gem -v
RUN jekyll -v

COPY ./ /srv/faq
WORKDIR /srv/faq
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "jekyll", "serve", "--livereload"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  faq-site:
    build: ./faq
    volumes:
      - ./faq:/srv/faq
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "35729:35729"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to bind against `0.0.0.0`. Then your site is reachable from an external ip.

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "jekyll", "serve", "--livereload", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```